# DAX with RankX and grouping others outside of top 5

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im trying to write the following DAX function to rank my top 5 countries based on visits.

Wrote this first which was successful:
Rank by country = RANKX(ALL('Export _ Country _ 2023'), 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Visits], , DESC)

Now when i want to in a new column assign others I have a problem with this code.

`VAR VAR_Rank = RANKX(ALL('Export _ Country _ 2023'), 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Visits], , DESC) RETURN IF(VAR_Rank <= 5, 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Label], "Others")`

It does not work, saying that the Return function is incorrect.

I have also tried this:

`VAR VAR_Rank = RANKX(ALL('Export _ Country _ 2023'), 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Visits], , DESC) RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(), VAR_Rank <= 5, 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Label], TRUE(), "Others"`

Do i need to refer to my Rank by country column and not to the original column?

`VAR VAR_Rank = RANKX(ALL('Export _ Country _ 2023'), 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Visits], , DESC) RETURN IF(VAR_Rank <= 5, 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Label], "Others")`

`VAR VAR_Rank = RANKX(ALL('Export _ Country _ 2023'), 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Visits], , DESC) RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(), VAR_Rank <= 5, 'Export _ Country _ 2023'[Label], TRUE(), "Others"`

Comment: Here you did declare a variable to work with but you did not specify what the column should return ( the value to show)